# DraftSight activation fails on Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: software-installation, cad

I have Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS with mate desktop. I installed DraftSight with these instructions:

https://www.3ds.com/products-services/draftsight-cad-software/free-download/

I downloaded deb file for ubuntu and installed it with

```
sudo dpkg -i draftSight.deb
```

Installation went without any errors.

When I start the DraftSight it asks activation. I fill all fields and press "activate" and then after few seconds the DraftSight crashes probably before sending any email.

Console output is as follows:

```
/opt/dassault-systemes/DraftSight/Linux/DraftSight
Could not parse stylesheet of object 0x21f5bd0
Could not parse stylesheet of object 0x21f5bd0
[15707:15707:0312/233839.681371:ERROR:child_thread_impl.cc(762)]
Request for unknown Channel-associated interface: ui::mojom::GpuMain
Created new window in existing browser session.
```

How can I fix this issue? Are there any packages that need to be installed before installing DraftSight?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: The output said `Created new window in existing browser session.`. Did you see this window? If not, look for it. If so, what was in it?

Comment: No I did not see any window. DraftSight crashed almost immediately after activate button press so any possible window was also closed soon after activate button press.

Comment: How about a new tab in Chrome/Chromium?

Comment: I have the same issue and my terminal message is :"Could not parse stylesheet of object 0x29fed50
Could not parse stylesheet of object 0x29fed50"